# Spring data rest application backend notify frontend

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

Hi I would like to my backend (spring-data-rest) application to generate some sample data and notify frontend. However the repository event handler is REST only so I tried to write a restTemplate but failed.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void addCounter() throws Exception {
    String url = String.format("http://localhost:%d/%s/counters", 8080, api);
    Counter counterExpected = new Counter('xxx', random.nextInt(100));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(counterExpected);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonString, headers);

    restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
}
```

Error:

```
Description:

Field restTemplate in ScheduledTask required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate' in your configuration.
```

This error makes sense because I am using TestTestTemplate in my runtime application instead of test scope.

My questions are:
Is it possible to change the addCounter() method to something simpler just like:

```
counterRepository.save(newCounter);
/* Raise AfterCreate event */
```

If yes, then how?

If not then is there any other way to do a HTTP post instead of using restTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I should be using

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

instead of

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
```